# Is there a reward per hash?

Tags: mining-profitability, mining-reward

So after reading some information about mining I wanted to know if the only reward for a miner is the block reward or if there a reward per hash, if yes how to find the amount a miner generate per hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reward is per block, it can't be per hash because the number of hashes a miner computed is not known to the network. Furthermore, only the miner who finds a block is rewarded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if i remind well the reward per block is x cryptocurency, but why do i win some cents when mining but not making block ? Its a litlle bit confusing, there a participation reward ?

Comment: If you mine with a pool, the mining pool will reward you based on the number of shares that you submit. However the Bitcoin network as a whole only pays to the miner (or mining pool) that solves a block.

Comment: Yeah this make more sens to me right now, thank you for your responses and your time :)